# Has anyone set up a HomeGroup across Windows 7 RC and Windows 7 RTM?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, homegroup

I'm wondering if all versions of Windows 7 on a home group network must match (e.g. all RC or all RTM)?  I was unable to add a new Windows 7 RTM to an existing Windows 7 RC HomeGroup.  It simply spins for a while after entering the password then eventually allows you to hit next again.

The troubleshooters (on both boxes) didn't fix it. I'd like to delay updating my media center to RTM until later.

I'm going to try taking down the HomeGroup and making a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can have a HomeGroup across Windows 7 RC and Windows 7 RTM.
I don't know what issue was blocking me intially but mixed RC and RTM was not the problem.

This is what worked for me to get the home group up: (I am not sure which steps were the minimal necessary.)

1. Remove the Windows 7 RC box from the HomeGroup.
2. Reboot both boxes.
3. Set up a new HomeGroup from the RC box.
4. Join the HomeGroup on the RTM box while the RC box HomeGroup screen is up.

Side note: I have a Windows home server running the beta of Powerpack3 (e.g. Windows 7 support), and have updated connector software on both Windows 7 boxes.  I did not touch the home server during the process.  I don't know if it contributed to my initial problem or not.